# mongoose pre function doesn't work on middle ware remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverless-framework

I have tries to delete referenced documents in mongoDb when Company is deleting.But after i execute following it only deletes the Company and not executing middle ware body

```
const removedCompany = await CompanyModel.findOne({ _id: id }).remove();
```

inside schema file

```
CompanySchema.pre('remove', (next) => {
  // 'this' is the company being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
  // to be notified of the calls' result.
  UserCompany.remove({ companyId: this._id }).exec();
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lambda function implements "this" as lexical this so it will not work
  use old style

```
CompanySchema.pre('remove', function(next){
 // 'this' is the company being removed. Provide callbacks here if you want
 // to be notified of the calls' result.
 UserCompany.remove({ companyId: this._id }).exec();
 next();
});
```

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#not-just-shorter-syntax-but-this

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html):

> **Note**: There is no query hook for `remove()`, only for documents. If you set a 'remove' hook, it will be fired when you call `myDoc.remove()`, not when you call `MyModel.remove()`.

If you rewrite your query to use [`findOneAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove), you can add a middleware/hook for that.

Also take into account Shubham's answer regarding arrow function expressions.